# "Subquery returned more than 1 value" when deleting records, not not if I change the number fetched

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to delete millions of records from 4 databases, and running into an unexpected error. I made a temp table that holds a list of all the id's I wish to delete:

```
CREATE TABLE #CaseList (case_id int)
INSERT INTO #CaseList 
SELECT DISTINCT id 
    FROM my_table
    WHERE <my criteria for choosing cases>
```

I have deleted all the associated records (with foreign key on case_id)

```
DELETE FROM image WHERE case_id in (SELECT case_id from #CaseList)
```

Then I'm deleting records from my_table in batches (so as not to blow up the transaction log - which despite my database being in Simple Mode - still grows when making changes like deletions):

```
DELETE FROM my_table WHERE id in (SELECT case_id
FROM #CaseList
ORDER by case_id
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 10000 ROWS ONLY)
```

This will work fine for one or three or five rounds (so I've deleted 10k-50k records), then will fail with this error message:

*Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure trgd_image, Line 188
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.*

Which is really weird because as I said, I already deleted all the associated records from the image table. Then it gets weirder because if I select smaller batches, the deletion works without error.

I generally cut the FETCH NEXT n half (5k), then in half again (2500), then in half again (1200) etc. until it works

```
DELETE FROM my_table WHERE id in (SELECT case_id
FROM #CaseList
ORDER by case_id
OFFSET 50000 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 1200 ROWS ONLY)
```

Then repeat that amount until I get past where it failed, then turn it back up to 10000 and it will work again for a batch or three...

```
DELETE FROM my_table WHERE id in (SELECT case_id
FROM #CaseList
ORDER by case_id
OFFSET 60000 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 10000 ROWS ONLY)
```

then fail again with the same error... rinse, wash, and repeat.

What can cause that subquery error when there are *NOT* related records in the image table? Why would selecting the cases in smaller batches work "around it" and then allow larger batches again?

I would really love a solution to this so I can make a WHILE loop and run this deletion through the millions of rows that way instead of having to manage it manually which is going to take me weeks with millions of rows needed to be deleted out of 4 databases.

Comment: are there partition on your table. I'm hoping it does esp based on million of rows. Can you start to look at the boundaries on the schema and see if you can leverage that. Pref: its on different filegroups and not just smashed on primary. Depending on your env you may have to involve a DBA. Though I'm sure your doing it in prod alrdy :D

Comment: Welcome to SO. This error is thrown on subqueries who are expecting ONLY one value. You should look for some query that will have something like: WHERE (select something from somewhere where somecondition)=5. By the way, could you provide us the code at line 188 and near it?

Comment: So what @GeorgeMenoutis is suggesting is try this SELECT top 20 case_id, Count_Check = count(1) FROM #CaseList group by case_id having count(1) > 1 ... and you can fire this query by itself. should give you some insight into why your sub-query is failing.

Comment: READ the error message. Did you notice the name it specifically mentions - trg_image? That sounds like the name of a trigger that has a hidden error in it that will only appear in certain situations. Go fix it.

Comment: Thank you the comments, they helped me figure it out. (Clearly, I am in over my head and dealing with a database which I cannot modify - and I know just enough to be dangerous!)  I tracked down the root of the problem, which was that there is another table  which I had forgotten about (specimens) with FK to cases, and a badly written trigger on the image table which throws that error if there's more than one image row associated with a specimen record. I am not allowed to modify the trigger, so I muddled out a way to delete those records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query you're showing cannot produce the error you're seeing.  If you're sure it is, you have a bug report.  My guess is that *trgd_image, Line 188* (or somewhere nearby) you'll find you're using a scalar comparison, `=` instead of `in`.

I also have some advice for you, free for the asking.  I wrote lots of queries like yours, and never used anything like `OFFSET 60000 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10000 ROWS ONLY`.  You don't *need* to, either, and your SQL will be easier to write if you don't.

First, unless your machine is seriously undersized for 2018 for the scale of data you're using, I think you'll find 100,000 row transactions are just fine.  If not, at least try to understand why not.  A machine managing many millions of rows ought to be able to deal with a 1% of them without breaking a sweat.

When you populate `#CaseList`, trap `@@rowcount`.  Then you can print/record that, and compute the number of "chunks" in your work.

Ideally, though, there's no temporary table.  Instead, those cases probably have some logical grouping you can operate on.  They might have regions or owners or dates, whatever was used to select them in the first place.  Iterate over that, e.g.

```
delete from T where id in (select id from S where user = 1
```

Once you do that, you can write a loop:

```
select @user = min(user) from S where ...
while @user is not NULL begin
    print "deleting cases for user", @user
    delete from T where id in (select id from S where user = @user)
    select @u = @user
    select @user = min(user) from S where ... and user > @u
end
```

That way, if the process blows up partway through -- for *any* reason -- you have a *logical* grouping of deletions and a clean break: you know all the cases for user (or whatever) less than `@user` are deleted, and you can look into what's wrong with the "current" one.  Quite often, you'll discover that the problem isn't unique, and by solving it you'll prevent future problems with others.